# detect error insert object in massive insert doctrine symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine for an application that the main task should import data from an CSV file into database. there are at least 50.000 entries. 
The code work perfect except one thing, detecting the row not inserted in the database.

```
if (($handle = fopen($rootPath, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
                set_time_limit(0);
                $tempObjets=array();
                while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ';')) !== FALSE) {
                    $iteration++;
                    $contactt = new Contact();
                    $option = array();
                    $optiondata = array();
                    $datacon = new Datacontact();


//precessing row data (read row and put the data into contact

  $datacon->setContact($contactt);
                                $em->persist($datacon);


                            $tempObjets[] = $datacon;

                            if ($iteration % 1000 == 0) {
                                try{

                                    $em->flush();
                                    $em->clear();
                                    foreach ($tempObjets as $tempObject) {
                                        $em->detach($tempObject);
                                    }
                                    $tempObjets = null;
                                    gc_enable();
                                    gc_collect_cycles();

                                }catch (\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException  $e )
                                {
                                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'error');
                                    $this->get('logger')->error($e->getMessage());

                                }
```

suppose that I the file csv containt 50000 entries, but just 45000 entries have been inserted, and 5000 entries contains error and I should put them in an array variables called for example errorsdata() that contain all error object.

How I can detect if a row has been inserted or not and how I add it to errorsdata variable given that script flush the data every 1000 iteration.

thanks for help